Cannot use Alarm Receiver Service on new Android 14
I am trying to get a notification on the selected days and time by the user but I got this error:
Calling startActivity() from outside of an Activity context requires the FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK flag. Is this really what you want?
I tried adding the flag  FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK to the intent , but if I add it then the notifications will not come. In all other devices works good except android 14, i don't have errors, the notification shows even if the app is killed but in Android 14 it crashes.
Does anybody have an idea how to fix it?
Here is my code
class AlarmReceiver : BroadcastReceiver() {

    override fun onReceive(context: Context, intent: Intent) {

        if ("android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" == intent.action) {
            AlarmUtil.scheduleAll(context)
            return
        }

        val dayOfWeek = intent.getIntExtra("Day", 2)
        AlarmUtil.scheduleAlarm(context, dayOfWeek, AppPreferences.hourOfDay, AppPreferences.minuteOfDay, true)

        val notificationId = Random().nextInt(60000)

        val notificationManager =
            context.getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE) as NotificationManager

        val channelId = App.instance.applicationContext.getString(R.string.message_notification_channel_id)
        val defaultSoundUri = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION)

        // Create the NotificationChannel, but only on API 26+ because
        // the NotificationChannel class is new and not in the support library
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            val name = App.instance.applicationContext.getString(R.string.message_notification_channel_name)
            val descriptionText = App.instance.applicationContext.getString(R.string.message_notification_channel_name)
            val importance = NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH
            val channel = NotificationChannel(channelId, name, importance).apply {
                description = descriptionText
                enableLights(true)
                enableVibration(true)

                if (defaultSoundUri != null) {
                    val att = AudioAttributes.Builder()
                        .setUsage(AudioAttributes.USAGE_NOTIFICATION)
                        .setContentType(AudioAttributes.CONTENT_TYPE_SONIFICATION)
                        .build()
                    setSound(defaultSoundUri, att)
                }

                lightColor = Color.parseColor("#501450")
            }
            notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(channel)
        }

        val newIntent = Intent(context, StartActivity::class.java)
        newIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP)
        newIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK)
        newIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK)
        newIntent.action = "actionString" + System.currentTimeMillis()
        val pendingIntent =
            PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, newIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_IMMUTABLE or PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT)

        val notificationBuilder = NotificationCompat.Builder(context, channelId)
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_notification)//a resource for your custom small icon
            .setColor(Color.parseColor("#222831"))
            .setContentText(App.instance.applicationContext.getString(R.string.remiderNotificationText))//ditto
            .setAutoCancel(true) //dismisses the notification on click
            .setSound(defaultSoundUri)
            .setVibrate(LongArray(0))
            .setDefaults(NotificationCompat.DEFAULT_ALL)
            .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_MAX)   // heads-up
            .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)

        notificationManager.notify(
            notificationId /* ID of notification */,
            notificationBuilder.build()
        )

    }
}

object AlarmUtil {
    private val alarmManager = App.instance.applicationContext.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE) as AlarmManager

    fun scheduleAlarm(context: Context?, dayOfWeek: Int, hourOfTheDay: Int, minuteOfTheDay: Int, repeating: Boolean) {
        val calendar = Calendar.getInstance()
        when(dayOfWeek){
            1 -> calendar[Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK] = Calendar.MONDAY
            2 -> calendar[Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK] = Calendar.TUESDAY
            3 -> calendar[Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK] = Calendar.WEDNESDAY
            4 -> calendar[Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK] = Calendar.THURSDAY
            5 -> calendar[Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK] = Calendar.FRIDAY
            6 -> calendar[Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK] = Calendar.SATURDAY
            7 -> calendar[Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK] = Calendar.SUNDAY
        }
        calendar[Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY] = hourOfTheDay
        calendar[Calendar.MINUTE] = minuteOfTheDay
        calendar[Calendar.SECOND] = 0

        if(repeating || calendar.timeInMillis < System.currentTimeMillis()){
            calendar.add(Calendar.DATE, 7)
        }

        val intent = Intent(context, AlarmReceiver::class.java)
        intent.putExtra("Day", dayOfWeek)
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK)
        val pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, dayOfWeek, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_IMMUTABLE)

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.S) {
            alarmManager.setExactAndAllowWhileIdle(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.timeInMillis, pendingIntent)
            return
        }

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.S) {
            if (!alarmManager.canScheduleExactAlarms()) {
                Intent().also {
                    it.action = Settings.ACTION_REQUEST_SCHEDULE_EXACT_ALARM
                    it.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK)
                    context?.startActivity(it)
                }
            }else {
                alarmManager.setExactAndAllowWhileIdle(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.timeInMillis, pendingIntent)
            }
        }
    }

    fun cancelAllAlarms(context: Context?) {
        val intent = Intent(context, AlarmReceiver::class.java)
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK)
        AppPreferences.selectedDays.fromPrettyJson<Array<String>>().forEach {
            val pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, it.toInt(), intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_IMMUTABLE)
            alarmManager.cancel(pendingIntent)
        }
    }

    fun scheduleAll(context: Context?) {
        if(AppPreferences.userNotifications && AppPreferences.specialUserNotifications){
            AppPreferences.selectedDays.fromPrettyJson<ArrayList<String>>().forEach {
                scheduleAlarm(context, it.toInt(), AppPreferences.hourOfDay, AppPreferences.minuteOfDay, false)
            }
        }
    }
}


class ReminderService : Service() {

    override fun onBind(p0: Intent?): IBinder? {
        return null
    }


    override fun onTaskRemoved(rootIntent: Intent) {
        super.onTaskRemoved(rootIntent)
        if(AppPreferences.selectedDays.isNotEmpty()){
            if(AppPreferences.specialUserNotifications) {
                AlarmUtil.scheduleAll(applicationContext)
            } else {
                AlarmUtil.cancelAllAlarms(applicationContext)
            }
        }
        this.stopSelf()
    }
}

class ReminderWorker(appContext: Context, workerParams: WorkerParameters) :
    CoroutineWorker(appContext, workerParams) {

    override suspend fun doWork(): Result {
        // Check if app is in foreground
        if (ProcessLifecycleOwner.get().lifecycle.currentState.isAtLeast(Lifecycle.State.STARTED)) {
            val intent = Intent(applicationContext, ReminderService::class.java)
            applicationContext.startService(intent)
        }

        return Result.success()
    }
}
//This is on my main activity:
val workRequest = OneTimeWorkRequestBuilder<ReminderWorker>().build()
            // Enqueue the work request
            WorkManager.getInstance(this).enqueue(workRequest)


If your project uses Android Jetpack, consider using WorkManager. This API provides a more structured way to schedule background tasks, including scheduling notifications.
